# Python requests: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python

I have a simple HTML page where I am trying to post form data using `requests.post()`; however, I keep getting `Bad Request 400. CSRF token missing or incorrect` even though I am passing it URL-encoded.
Please help.

```
url = "https://recruitment.advarisk.com/tests/scraping"

res = requests.get(url)

tree = etree.HTML(res.content)
csrf = tree.xpath('//input[@name="csrf_token"]/@value')[0]

postData = dict(csrf_token=csrf, ward=wardName)
print(postData)
postUrl = urllib.parse.quote(csrf)

formData = dict(csrf_token=postUrl, ward=wardName)
print(formData)
headers = {'referer': url, 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.post(url, data=formData, headers=headers)
return page.content
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have make sure the `requests` in one session, so that the `csrf_token` will be matched:

```
import sys
import requests

wardName = "DHANLAXMICOMPLEX"

url = 'https://recruitment.advarisk.com/tests/scraping'

#make the requests in one session
client = requests.session()
# Retrieve the CSRF token first
tree = etree.HTML(client.get(url).content)
csrf = tree.xpath('//input[@name="csrf_token"]/@value')[0]
#form data
formData = dict(csrf_token=csrf, ward=wardName)
headers = {'referer': url, 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}
#use same session client
r = client.post(url, data=formData, headers=headers)
print r.content
```

It will give you the html with the result data table.